# A request from a private subnet to a public subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

My VPC has two subnets - public and private.

The public subnet contains ECS Fargate Task:

```
Network mode -> awsvpc
ENI Id -> eni-xxxxxxxxxx
Private IP -> 10.0.0.36
Public IP -> 34.243.XXX.XXX
```

The private subnet contains a Lambda function.

When I try to connect from Lambda at IP 10.0.0.36 I get the error:

```json
{
  "errorType":"Error",
  "errorMessage":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 10.0.0.36:3000",
  "trace":[
    "Error:getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 10.0.0.36:3000",
    "at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)"
  ]
}
```

how can this be corrected?

PS. Internet access is not required for Lambda.

**Addition:**

Simplified code of my Lambda:

```js
const http = () => {
    const body = '{"vehicles":[{"id":0,"profile":"driving-car","start":[32.41,34.784],"end":[32.41,34.784]}],"jobs":[{"id":0,"location":[32.41,34.784]},{"id":1,"location":[32.480,34.835]}],"options":{"g":true}}';
    const options = {
        hostname: '10.0.0.36:3000',
        path: '/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength( body ),
        }
    };
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const req = require('http' ).request(options, res => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8'); 
            var str = '';
            res.on('data', chunk => str += chunk);
            res.on('end', () => resolve(str));
        });
        req.write(body);
        req.end();
    });
};
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: await http(),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Group on the ENI of the Fargate task? It is probably not permitting inbound access on that port.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. HTTP|TCP|80|0.0.0.0/0; Custom TCP|TCP|3000|0.0.0.0/0

Comment: At the same time, when I run Task not through a Lambda, but directly from the Internet, everything works.

Comment: Is the Lambda function connecting to the task's Public IP address, or Private IP address?

Comment: Lambda knocking on the Private IP. I have added Lambda code to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that the post can be part of the hostname? I'm just asking because [Making HTTP requests with Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) shows it as a separate field.

Comment: Uuups... Thank you very much! And then I have already re-read all the VPC documentation (I learned a lot :)). Please post this as an answer so I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Making HTTP requests with Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) shows some sample code as:

```js
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'whatever.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'GET'
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

I notice that they have listed the `port:` as a separate field, rather than adding it to the `hostname`.

Your code, however, shows:

```
hostname: '10.0.0.36:3000'
```

Try providing the `hostname` and `port` as separate fields.